# asp.net core redirect to https

Tags: redirect, https, asp.net-core-2.0

We have a multi-tenant asp.net core 2 application.

We need to redirect to their https the requests to non-secure url. We have to do this by code instead using the web.config or IIS, since some domains have https and some others not. We check which domain needs this redirection by checking in a database based on the host making the request.

Is it possible to do this in a middleware?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what we need and I'd like to share in case someone else has the same problem.

We have solved it with URL Rewrite rules using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite library.

In the startup.cs we add the following code

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectToSecureRule()));
```

Then we add the class RedirectToSecureRule

```
public class RedirectToSecureRule : IRule
{
    public virtual void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var currentRequest = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (currentRequest.IsHttps)
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        if (currentRequest.Host.Host.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        if (context.HttpContext.Items["TenantSsl"] == null || !Convert.ToBoolean(context.HttpContext.Items["TenantSsl"]))
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        var httpsUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute("https", new HostString(currentRequest.Host.Value), currentRequest.PathBase, currentRequest.Path, currentRequest.QueryString);

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = 301;
        response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location] = httpsUrl;

        context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    }
}
```

As you see if the request is already https we don't do anything. The same for localhost, although this condition is not necessary since we can also work with https in localhost.

Then we check if HttpContext.Items["TenantSsl"] is true. This is because our app is a multi-tenant app where we share the codes and the IIS pool but each tenant has its own database.

It could happen that one tenant has a SSL certificate and others not, that's the reason we have to add a field in our tenant's database to check that.

Before this Rule is executed, we execute the tenant selector, where we add to the HttpContext.Items a bool variable indicating is the current tenant has a SSL certificate-

Finally, if the tenant has a SSL certificate and the request is not https, we redirect to the https page.

May thanks to Ray Huang, we based this solution on one of his posts:
https://blog.discountasp.net/3-ways-to-redirect-http-to-https-and-non-www-to-www-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate on `Before this Rule is executed, we execute the tenant selector, where we add to the HttpContext.Items a bool variable indicating is the current tenant has a SSL certificate` part?
I used your code but it didn't work for me at all.